# Isotope Filtering with HTML5 Data Attributes instead of CSS classes

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, custom-data-attribute

Need some assistance or guidance on using HTML 5 Data Attributes instead of CSS classes to filter content with Isotope.

I have currently implemented a fully working content filter which works perfectly but I need to use custom data attributes on the items to be filtered.

In essence my markup for the items to be filtered is as follows:

```
<div class="col-4"    
data-featured="no"
data-bedroom="3"
data-bathroom="2"
data-garages="0"
data-province="gauteng"
data-city="sandton"
data-suburb="morningside"
data-listing-type="rent"
data-property-type="apartment"
data-property-size="0"
data-land-size="0"
data-price="12000"
data-agents="310061">
<!-- Item content here -->
</div>
```

This is so that I can filter out divs that for example; are 3 bedroom units. Using CSS classes for this I feel results in a ton of overhead and feels very dirty. Is there a way to make use of the custom data attributes to filter the values rather than CSS classes?

I currently have the following JS code to handle the filtering but it needs to be adapted to make use of the data attributes rather than CSS classes and I have been unable to find a solution online or on the Isotope documentation. I assume that a filter function would be required but that is where I fall short of a working out a solution.

```
// Isotope
var filters = {};    
    
var $grid = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.isotope-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
});
    
$('.filters').on( 'change', function( event ) {
    var $select = $( event.target );
    var filterGroup = $select.attr('value-group');
    filters[ filterGroup ] = event.target.value;
    var filterValue = concatValues( filters );
    $grid.isotope({ filter: filterValue });
});

function concatValues( obj ) {
    var value = '';
    for ( var prop in obj ) {
        value += obj[ prop ];
    }
    return value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use jquery attribute selectors:

```
$grid.isotope({ filter: '[data-price=80]'});
```

You can find more about [jquery selectors.](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)